# Inserting multiple rows into mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

Am having a problem inserting multiple rows of data into a table at once. The following is what i have.When i click on submit, only the last row is inserted with only the first digit of quantity. please help.

html form:

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
<p><input type="text"  id="product_id" name="product_id[]"/>  
   <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity[]"/></p>
<p><input type="text"  id="product_id" name="product_id[]"/>  
   <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity[]"/></p>
<p><input type="text"  id="product_id" name="product_id[]"/>  
   <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity[]"/></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

insert.php page:

```
<?php 
include 'config/auth.php';//database connection 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $product = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['product_id']);
    $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['quantity']);
    $count = sizeof($product);
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $Inproduct = $product[$i];
        $Inquantity = $quantity[$i];
    $query = "INSERT INTO sales (product_id, quantity) VALUES ('$Inproduct','$Inquantity')";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    }
    if ($results) {
        echo 'Success';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You failed to describe what your problem actually is. Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also you're running mysqli_real_escape_string() on an array not a string. Run that function within the loop. E.g. on $product[$i] and $quantity[$i]

Comment: @CBroe i have just edited the question

Comment: @kmdm thanks alot for helping me. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code worked... thanks @kmdm

```
    $product = $_POST['product_id'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $count = sizeof($product);
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $Inproduct = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $product[$i]);
        $Inquantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $quantity[$i]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO sales (product_id, quantity) VALUES ('$Inproduct','$Inquantity')";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    }
```